# How to use methods defined in anonymous class outside of it?

Tags: java, object, anonymous-class

May I know how can I use/call the age method? Here is the Student class.

```
class Student {
    public static void address(){
        System.out.println("streetB");
    }
}
public class School {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student gg = new Student() {
            public void age() {
                System.out.println("9");

            }
        };
        //how to call age() method here?
    }
}
```

Comment: `gg.age()`, just like any other method?

Comment: @cricket_007 does not work, the class `Student` has no `age` method, would only work for `address` or when declaring `gg` with `var`

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for something different, as you just created new class here that extends `Student` class, but it is anonymous so you can just access that new method as it does not belong to `Student` class.

If you are using java 10 then you can use `var`

```
class Student {
    public static void address(){
        System.out.println("streetB");
    }
}
public class School {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var gg = new Student() {
            public void age() {
                System.out.println("9");

            }
        };
        gg.age();
    }
}
```

But that would be probably pretty bad idea, as there is just no reason to do such weird thing.

(`var` works here because it can represent that anonymous class at compile time)

You should probably add age field and method to `Student` class

Answer (score 0):

Since `gg` is declared as `Student` and there is no `age()` method in that class, compiler will not allow you to call `gg.age()` because it is not guaranteed that every Student instance will be able to support it.

#### Pre java 10 solutions (if you are using Java 10 or later read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51674290))

What you can try is *reflection* mechanism through which you can

- `gg.getClass()` to get class literal representing actual type of object held by `gg` variable,
- then `getDeclaredMethod("age")` to get `age` method declared in that class,
- then `invoke(gg)` to call that method on object held by `gg`.

In short

```
gg.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("age").invoke(gg);
```

---

Other way would be not assigning created instance of anonymous class to any reference which would limit its possibility and call method directly on created object like

```
new Student() {
    public void age() {
        System.out.println("9");
    }
}.age();
```

but this way we can't reuse that object anywhere later (because we don't have reference to it).

Comment: You could get that reference in second example, but I don't even want to show such dirty code :D as you could get it from constructor/initializer